# PowerShell Unzip Access Denied

Tags: powershell, user-accounts

I have a PowerShell script that is supposed to unzip some files in a directory, but when I run it it throws this error:

```
Exception calling "ExtractToDirectory" with "2" argument(s): "Access to the path 
'E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3' is denied."
At line:7 char:5
+     [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, "E:\SubFolder\Sub ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccessException
```

I have given myself full control to each individual folder in the path and run as administrator (just to test) and it still throws the error.

Here is my code

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

function Unzip
{
    param([string]$zipfile)

    [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, "E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3")

}

$Files = get-childitem "E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3"

foreach ( $i in $files ) 
{
    Unzip "SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\$i" 
}
```

Could someone point me in the right direction to get this working?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate the error but maybe try adding a `Where` clause in the `Get-ChildItem`: `get-childitem "E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3" | Where { $_.Extension -eq ".zip" }`

Comment: That has done the trick. Post your answer below and I will accept. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `Where` in the `Get-ChildItem`

```
Get-ChildItem "E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3" | Where { $_.Extension -eq ".zip" }
```

I would also suggest you change the argument when calling Unzip function to

`Unzip $i.FullName`

Comment: `Get-ChildItem "E:\SubFolder\SubFolder2\SubFolder3\*.zip"` would work as well.